# Export a png from kra, a krita document

Tags: linux, image, command-line, imagemagick, export

I am developing a all in one image converter tool using bash commands.  So I want to know how to export a krita, ".kra" document with many layers, to a "png" image using command line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a command line converter for Krita. However from version 2.9 it was removed in favor of calling krita binary with arguments.

If krita version is 2.8 or less you should use calligraconverter

```
calligraconverter --batch -- input output
```

In 2.9 you would call krita like this

```
krita input --export --export-filename output
```

By default both commands output format is based on the output extension name. For more information run calligraconverter (2.8) OR krita(2.9) commands "--help".

Answer (score 1):

Not a ready command-line utility solution as you wanted but still.

Found following python script from [David Revoy's blog](http://www.davidrevoy.com/article82/krita-kra-file-thumbnailer-for-gnome-nautilus-linux)

Try to adapt it to your needs.

```
import sys, zipfile
import Image
import StringIO

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    sys.exit('Usage: '+sys.argv[0]+' <Input> <Output> <Size>')

thumbnail = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1]).read('preview.png')

im = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(thumbnail))
im.thumbnail( (int(sys.argv[3]), int(sys.argv[3])) )

im.save(sys.argv[2],'png')
```